# Combine Flux (vuex) store with global event bus?

Tags: vue.js, flux, vuex

I'm using Vuex & Vuejs (flux architect) for a CRM single page application.
In contact page i'm showing a list of tasks related to current contact and at sidebar i have a list of task for current logged in user.

These collection of tasks are kept in separate stores. I don't know which is best solution:

1. After update post request search in both list and update task object if it's present and mutate state.
2. After update post request use an global event bus and each store should listen and update task object if needed.

Comment: Why did you choose to have multiple stores? The point of Vuex is to have all of your application state in one place, so you don't have to use things like a global event bus.

Comment: I mean multiple collections. because list of user tasks is totally separate from current exploring contact tasks but in some situation they may have tasks in common. For example user has 10 task for today in sidebar and currently is exploring a contact that his last task was completed a year ago or he is exploring a contact which user has a related task for today (in sidebar).
@EricGuan

Answer (score 2):

It really depends of your requirements, but one thing I can tell is that using two separated stores + bus is defeating the whole purpose of Redux.

If the tasks in your application share the same scope and can be assigned to you or other users that you may be visiting/managing, you can have all the tasks from your scope (your team, for example) and display it on different places using different getters with Array.filter functions.

If the number of tasks is too big to have it all loaded, I'd approach it doing one single tasks list in the store, being populated from a single url.

ie:
 - Give me all the tasks I have + the tasks of current user I'm managing
 - Give me all the tasks I have + the tasks that matches this search

Although this can get messy if the requirements are more complicated and can get confusing. But try to structure your application with one single store if possible and avoid bus, as it is only recommended for small size applications.